# Tampermonkey @match not working when visit target link through redirection

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

- Chrome: Version 87.0.4280.67
- Tampermonkey: v4.11

I'm trying to add a button to `https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/*`. But when I search on https://academic.microsoft.com/home and select any result to redirect to `https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/*`, the script won't run as expected. To trigger the user script, I need to refresh the website.

For example:

1. Add a test user script

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test Userscript
// @match        https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    alert("Matched");
})();
```

2. Search anything on https://academic.microsoft.com/home
3. Press any result title to go to the detail page `https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/*`
4. The user script won't run
5. Refresh the website, the script runs

Comment: This is the correct behavior. This is a Single Page Application site that uses programmatic navigation. You need to match the entire site and check the URL inside using MutationObserver or other techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954).